# How to display records correctly using <asp:Repeater>

Tags: asp.net

I have been searching for an answer to this issue without success. 
My query involves one table and one of the columns (Column2 as an example) has multiple values.
I would like to display information on the web using ASP.NET Repeater.

If I run this query (`Select * from TableName where Column1 = ‘Apple’`) then my SQL database table looks like this:

[image]

I have 2 ASP.NET pages (`master.aspx` and `details.aspx`)
master.aspx has a link like this http://localhost:1234/Folder/details.aspx?Column1=SomeStringValues
`details.aspx` has the following code (no code-behind code):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1" >          
           <HeaderTemplate>
            <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 80px">Column1</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 120px">Column2</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblColumn1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblColumn2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column2") %>' /> </td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM TableName WHERE Column1= @ Column1">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name=" Column1" QueryStringField=" Column1" Type="String" DefaultValue="<%= Column1%>" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to group your data, and then probably use another repeater inside of the main repeater to list all the Column2 values for each Column1 value.

```
<repeater>
    Column1 = <%# Eval("Column1") %>
    <repeater>
       //for each Column2 value, print value here
    </repeater
</repeater
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tip.
I revised my code to use nested Repeater per your recommendation but the output is not right. Maybe I am not doing it right?

[Output can be found from this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIGpo.png)

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCol1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1" >          

  <ItemTemplate>
  <p><strong>Column1: <%# Eval("Column1") %></strong><br />
  <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCol2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>

     Column2: <%# Eval("Column2") %><br />

    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  </p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```